# Fixed Width Sidebar, Fluid Content area with 100% width table

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've got this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpxeF/1793/

with the following CSS:

```
.sidebar{ 
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
}
.content {
    background: green;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

The problem is the table, due to having set it at 100% it actually goes below the sidebar. If I remove the width: 100% rule it works fine, but I need the table to use up all the space of the parent div container.. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Is the table a child or sibling of `.content`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a css guy but i think you need to add width and float-left for content div too. You need something like

```
.content {
    background: green;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rhzky40e/

Answer (score 2):

A more common and I think better solution is to use a margin that's the size of your sidebar to stop your content from flowing under your sidebar:

```
#fixedWidth{ 
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}
#theRest{
    background: green;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinfunk/nj3exy36/)

Comment: this solved the content flowing under for me - thank you

Answer (score 1):

i think this might work

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar">Fixed<br />Sidebar<br />Goes<br />Here</div>
<div class="content">
    <table>
        <tr><td>test If a !DOCTYPE is not specified, the border-collapse property can produce unexpected results in IE8 and earlier versions.</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebar{ 
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
}
.content {
    background: green;
    float: left;
     width: calc(100% - 200px);
}    
table {

    background:#ccc;
}
```

Link : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/hbrqj3hd/)

Answer (score 1):

Today (end of 2015) you could do this instead (works for IE8/9 as well).

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
.sidebar{ 
    width: 200px;
    background: yellow;
}
.content {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell sidebar">
      Fixed<br />Sidebar<br />Goes<br />Here
    </div>
    <div class="cell content">
      Test
    </div>
</div>
```

Or with flex for the newest browsers.

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.sidebar{ 
    width: 200px;
    background: yellow;
}
.content {
    flex: 1;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="sidebar">Fixed<br />Sidebar<br />Goes<br />Here
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```